# How to make postage stamp sheet?

Tags: tables, graphics, diagrams

I am looking around for template to make postage stamp sheet, with standard sizes and ability to preview stamp cuts. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Can you share a sketch of how the result should look like?

Comment: I assume something like this:
https://www.ceskaposta.cz/documents/10180/4927016/Brana_pav_kocour_v.jpg/62ec3bcd-3891-189d-0822-c123afdb34e3?t=1515488526116

Comment: A matrix of tikz nodes might be a possible approach, see e.g. https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices

Comment: @AlexanderWeps, just a hint: an EDITED question is a good place to provide such extra information in a consistent way. So the image, not its link, has a good place there.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possibility with `nicematrix`. You have to compile twice (which randomly changes the ducks).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\newcommand{\borderw}{2mm}
\newcommand{\duck}{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=3cm, valign=m]{example-image-duck}}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2mm}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 2mm}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{7}{c}}
\duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck \\
\duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck \\
\duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck % \goose
\CodeAfter\tikz[line cap=round, line width=1mm, dash pattern=on 0mm off 2mm, gray!50, shorten <=-1cm, shorten >=-1cm]{
  \foreach \n in {1,...,8}\draw(1-|\n)--(4-|\n);
  \foreach \n in {1,...,4}\draw(\n-|1)--(\n-|8);
}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In complement to Sandy G's answer, here another answer using `nicematrix`. It defines a customized line style (with the key `custom-line` in `\NiceMatrixOptions`) and uses in the `{NiceTabular}` with the letter `I` (for the vertical rules) and the command `MyHline` for the horizontal ones.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\newcommand{\borderw}{2mm}
\newcommand{\duck}{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=3cm, valign=m]{example-image-duck}}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2mm}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    cell-space-limits = 2mm ,
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = I , 
       command = MyHline ,
       tikz = 
         {
           line cap=round, 
           line width=1mm, 
           dash pattern=on 0mm off 2mm, 
           gray!50, 
           shorten <=-1cm, 
           shorten >=-1cm
         }
     }
  }

\begin{NiceTabular}{cIcIcIcIcIcIc}
\MyHline
\duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck \\
\MyHline
\duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck \\
\MyHline
\duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck & \duck \\
\MyHline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]