# Overlaying different text boxes onto tiled images

Tags: numbering, overlays, includegraphics, datatool, envlab

I have used this solution from [How to make postage stamp sheet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673627/how-to-make-postage-stamp-sheet), I can scale my image, produce any type of image tiling pattern and define exact cutting guides, I would like to have some other features though, below is my MWE.

Each .tex file will have its own unique image and quantity to be printed on A4 portrait pages, and data.
My MWE has 12 (3c x 4r) image tiles, at other times a different c x r will be chosen, I would like to include the following;

- a date dd/mm/yyyy text aligned left and aligned top and left of each image
- an incrementing number from n to m of m, say 1 of 145, 2 of 145, 3 of 145, ...
- a newline under n of m, say the word "metric" or "allowed", both are text aligned right and aligned top and right of each image
- some fixed text placed at a definable but fixed position on each image

Is this at all possible ?  I have tried [envlab](/questions/tagged/envlab) with [datatool](/questions/tagged/datatool) as this has the promise of using an external file for the variables (text file) but I could not get this to work.  I've also tried [label](/questions/tagged/label) but couldn't get graphics, probably not allowed.
Some 40 years ago I used industrial labelling software that did exactly this but I could not find any such thing within latex.  A sheet of stamps seemed the nearest thing to me, but I'd welcome other solutions or packages to do the same thing. I'm using TeXstudio, also my MWE has a blank first page!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[portrait]{geometry} %originally landscape
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

%\newcommand{\borderw}{1mm}
\newcommand{\duck}{\includegraphics[width=6.3cm, height=6.6cm, valign=m]{example-image-duck}}
%\newcommand{\duck}{\includegraphics[width=.42\textwidth,valign=m]{sundewcoverreducedsize.jpg}}

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5mm} %horizontal gap between image and borderline
    \advance\leftskip-3.0cm %gap from left edge of paper page to content
%   \vspace*{-2.5cm} %gap from top edge of paper page to content
    \NiceMatrixOptions
    {
        cell-space-limits = 0.5mm , %vertical gap between image and borderline
        custom-line = 
        {
            letter = I , 
            command = MyHline ,
            tikz = 
            {
                line cap=round, 
                line width=1mm, 
                dash pattern=on 0mm off 2mm, 
                gray!50, 
                shorten <=-1cm, 
                shorten >=-1cm
            }
        }
    }
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{IcIcIcI}
        \MyHline
        \duck & \duck & \duck \\
        \MyHline
        \duck & \duck & \duck \\
        \MyHline
        \duck & \duck & \duck \\
        \MyHline
        \duck & \duck & \duck \\
        \MyHline
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}
```

This hand edit shows what I'm looking for
[image: A hopeful result]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: @barbarabeeton many thanks for the welcome

Comment: I've used the `labels` package for all kinds of labels, though I haven't made any for a while. It has an optional grid. Or maybe try something like `tcolorbox`? That would let you integrate a counter for numbering, for example, and is highly configurable.

Comment: @cfr thank you for the advice. I've tried labels which I thought would be the perfect solution but I could not get the graphics to load.  I had a grid but that was all, I didn't continue with placing any text until I could get the images tiled correctly.

Comment: @cfr thank you for the reply. I've tried [tag:labels] which I thought would be the perfect solution but I could not get the graphics to load.  I had a grid but that was all, I didn't continue with placing any text until I could get the images tiled correctly.  [tag:tcolorbox] looks a bit more promising from the example pdf.  I will have a play with that and update in due course

Comment: @cfr I've had a look at [tag:tcolorbox] and the best choice is [tag:tcbposter], but could not find graphics with text overlay examples, just graphics inside boxes.  I also tried the library raster but to no avail.  So not suitable, especially if there were 3000 tiles to print.  I'm currently looking at [tag:overpic]

Comment: I've had no issues using graphics in `labels` labels .... `tcolorbox` has all the overlay possibilities of Ti*k*Z and more. That can be a bit engine dependent, though I'm not sure that'd be an issue here. On the other hand, it would definitely be slower than `labels` or `overpic`.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure I really understand what you're trying to do. What is supposed to be generated and what specified? What is the format of the data file and where are the images? Are the dates the same? The pictures? Do you want to specify different texts in different positions per image?